# how to get custom exception message in ajaxError of jquery

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, exception

I know we can get exception using `xhr.responseText`, but in my APP, the `responseText`display as exception description amended by Tomcat. please refer to below image, is there anyone can tell me how can I control the content of `responseText` or how to handle custom message(may be in a better way).
I need a title and content in the response as I can display them in dialog of Jquery UI. BTW, I throw a general exception just like `throw new Exception("some error happens");`

[image]

Comment: How about catching the exception?

Comment: in the background, I just raised a exception when catch this request, no another logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define custom error message in your `web.xml` like this -

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/Error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

You can have any text in your error.jsp page, that text will be sent to client on respective error

[more info](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/custom-error-pages.html)

Comment: I will have a try first.